# How can I put style.css latest file?

Tags: css, wordpress

in wordpress how can I put style.css lastest file of all stylesheet file?

I tried

```
function stylecssAlwaysLast() {
    wp_register_style( 'mystyle', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/style.css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'mystyle' );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','stylecssAlwaysLast',1000);
```

but *add* file last but dont remove the style.css add by default wordpress code. In other words: at the last i've two files style.css :-(

**UPDATE**

I get it! :-)

Goals:

1. remove default theme style.css;
2. my stylesheet must to be the latest item;
3. if exist the compressed version use it in place of default versione;

...and the answers is...:

```
function styleCompressedLatest() {
    // delete style.css
    wp_dequeue_style('wp-bootstrap');
    wp_deregister_style('wp-bootstrap');

    // text if exist compressed version
    if(file_exists(get_stylesheet_directory().'/style_compressed.css')) {
        $style = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/style_compressed.css';
    } else {
        $style = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/style.css';
    }

    // add my style.css
     wp_enqueue_style( 'mystyle', $style);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','styleCompressedLatest',1000);
```

Somebody knows a best way?

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, just don't call your stylesheet `style.css` and both will be included.

Also, you don't need to `register` and `enqueue` a style if you are only using it once, just use `wp_enqueue_style()` as below.

```
function stylecssAlwaysLast() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'mystyle', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/mystyle.css');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','stylecssAlwaysLast',1000);
```